# how can I install docker in yocto (runqemu)?

Tags: docker, yocto, qemu

I installed yocto and connected to VM.
*I used command 'runqemu qemuarm64 core-image-full-cmdline nographic'

how can I install docker in yocto?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ubuntu's precompiled packages in a Yocto based system. At least not without some really hard work. Ubuntu probably uses a different toolchain, different base packages and different distro policies to what Poky (what I assume you're running) normally sets.

You'll have to build and install Docker in your image from source. This is canon way of getting packages installed in an image through Yocto.

A simplified gist of what you'll need to do:

1. Clone [meta-virtualization](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-virtualization/) to your local workspace. This is where the docker recipe is.
2. Add this layer to the build. See the command `bitbake-layers`
3. Add docker to your image. There are many ways to do this but adding `IMAGE_INSTALL += "docker-ce"` to your `local.conf` will sufice.
4. Rebuild your image and hope for the best.

I have shipped Docker into a Poky based image in the past, and the steps above were not enough. I had to [enable some kernel flags](https://github.com/bernardocrodrigues/meta-cosmic/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/files/docker-config.cfg) to have everything working properly.